# Fine control of AudioRecord

Tags: sound, data-acquisition

I use an external sound card (Fireface UCX) for data acquisition, generating stimulus .wav files with Mathematica, using Audacity to simultaneously play the stimulus and record several channels of system response, then analyzing the response .wav files in Mathematica. I would very much like to automate this process completely within Mathematica.

There are a number of issues to get this working, but the foremost on my mind is how do I exert any kind of control over `AudioRecord`? The documented interface only allows me to control the input device, max duration, and storage method. Going one level deeper, I can define an input `AudioStream` and pass it to `AudioRecord`, but I cannot set basic parameters of the `AudioStream` such as `SampleRate` or `AudioChannelAssignment`.

I recognize that `AudioRecord` is still experimental (as of 11.3) and it is very possible that these features are simply not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to close it out. It does not appear to be possible to set `SampleRate` or `AudioChannelAssigment` for audio recordings as of 11.3. This has been submitted as a feature request [CASE:4072527].